# PHP mySQL search not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, search, search-engine

```
<?php
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
     $hostname = "localhost";

     $db_handle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect to database");

     $selected= mysql_select_db("login", $db_handle);

     $output='';

     if(isset($_POST['search'])){
         $searchq = $_POST['search'];

         $query= "SELECT * FROM PHP_Item WHERE Name LIKE '%searchq%' OR Description LIKE '%serachq%'" or die ("could not search");
         $result= mysql_query($query);
         $count= mysql_num_rows($result);

         echo $count;

         if($count <1){
             $output = 'there were no search results';
         }else{
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                 $mName = $row['Name'];
                 $price = $row['Price'];
                 $id= $row['ItemID'];

                 $output .= '<div>'.$mName.' '.$price.'</div>';
             }
         }
     }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Movie Search-Search for a movie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="search.php" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Find movies..."/>
              <input type="submit" value="Search movies"/>
        </form>

            <?php print("$output");?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Im trying to impliment a search bar on my website where users can enter the name of a movie and it will return movies with the same or a similar name to the user's search.

The database being searched has 3 fields-->> ItemID, Name, Description.
I keep getting 0 results with the 'there were no search results' output. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: in the query try adding the $ before searchq, otherwise it would be considered the string ''searchq" ie - change '%searchq%' to '%$searchq%'

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

**Firstly**, you left out the dollar signs for the variables, which *technically-speaking*, you would be searching for the "searchq" or "serachq" literal strings. "serachq" being a typo as mentioned below.

```
'%searchq%' OR Description LIKE '%serachq%'
```

as per `$searchq = $_POST['search'];`

Plus, you also made a typo in the word `serachq` in `LIKE '%serachq%'`

Rewrite:

```
'%$searchq%' OR Description LIKE '%$searchq%'
```

- Checking for errors would have spotted those.

Your `or die ("could not search");` in your query, that doesn't help. See my note below about adding `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

**Then this line**:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

that should be referencing `$result` in `$result= mysql_query($query);` and not `$query`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

You also have what seems to be commented out code in your HTML, and is broken; double-check that in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> --><!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

- Which will break you page.
- Just change that whole block to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Conditional statements options:**

This line: `if(isset($_POST['search']))` could also be changed to

```
if( 
    isset($_POST['search']) && 
    !empty($_POST['search']) 
    )
```

in order to make sure that the input wasn't left empty.

or simply:

```
if( !empty($_POST['search']) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @sємsєм, but I needed to make an additional edit at the bottom of my answer, but I have kept your edit; thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I've only just started learning PHP which is why I'm making these silly mistakes. Next time i'll take more care when checking my code for errors.